# how to get my AMD GPU to work under debian?

Tags: debian, gpu, hdmi, amd

Okay guys i lost all hope to solve this problem.
I have a dell m4800 which supports 2 gpu's Intel and AMD m5100.
i tried everything to get the AMD GPU to work but with no luck, the main problem is that the HDMI port is connected to the AMD GPU and i cant get it to work.

here is my xrandr output :

```
$xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0xdd cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:VERDE @ pci:0000:01:00.0*
```

so i cant tell it sees the GPU but i cant use it:
the out put for inxi -G:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: AMD Venus XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X] driver: radeon v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: ati,modesetting,radeon 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.1.2
```

i checked archwiki but unfortunately with no luck to solve the problem.
any help would be great.

thanks

''''''''''''''''

```
Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 17707.015] Build Operating System: Linux 4.19.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[ 17707.015] Current Operating System: SMP Debian 5.6.14-2 (2020-05-23) x86_64
[ 17707.015] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-2Debian-amd64 root=UUID=41ce03bf-3470-48db-92d9-0552d7f254ac ro quiet splash noautomount quiet
[ 17707.015] Build Date: 31 March 2020  10:14:40AM
[ 17707.015] xorg-server 2:1.20.8-2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[ 17707.015] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[ 17707.015]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 17707.015] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 17707.015] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Jul 29 19:24:47 2020
[ 17707.015] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 17707.016] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 17707.016] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 17707.016] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 17707.016] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 17707.016] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 17707.016] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 17707.016] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 17707.016] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 17707.016] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 17707.016] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 17707.016]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 17707.016] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[ 17707.016] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 17707.016] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 17707.016] (II) Loader magic: 0x55bb4bc32e20
[ 17707.016] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 17707.016]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 17707.016]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
[ 17707.016]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[ 17707.016]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 17707.017] (--) using VT number 2

[ 17707.017] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 17707.018] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 17707.018] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[ 17707.018] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[ 17707.018] (EE) /dev/dri/card1: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[ 17707.020] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0416:1028:05cc rev 6, Mem @ 0xf5800000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 17707.020] (--) PCI: (1@0:0:0) 1002:6821:1028:05cc rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf7c00000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 17707.020] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 17707.020] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 17707.021] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17707.021]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[ 17707.021]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 17707.021] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 17707.021] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 17707.021] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 17707.021] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 17707.021] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 17707.021] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 17707.021] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17707.021]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.20.8
[ 17707.021]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 17707.021]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[ 17707.021] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 17707.021] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 17707.021] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17707.021]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[ 17707.021]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 17707.021]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 17707.021] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[ 17707.021] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 17707.021] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17707.021]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0
[ 17707.021]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 17707.021]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 17707.021] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 17707.021] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 17707.021] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[ 17707.350] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[ 17707.350] (II) modeset(1): using default device
[ 17707.350] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[ 17707.350] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 17707.350] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[ 17707.350] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17707.350]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 0.0.2
[ 17707.350]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[ 17707.350] (**) FBDEV(2): claimed PCI slot 0@0:2:0
[ 17707.350] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[ 17707.350] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[ 17707.350] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[ 17707.350] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 17707.350] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[ 17707.350] (EE) 
[ 17707.350] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 17707.350] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[ 17707.350] (EE) 
[ 17707.399] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.``
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in logs you pasted. If this command:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo -B | grep renderer
```

shows OpenGL information for AMD GPU, then everything is fine - you can use DRI_PRIME to select the GPU per application/game.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, but the HDMI output is not working. it only works for one 1 sec during boot loading screen then it disappears and the HDMI is not detected

Comment: It seems you think that "HDMI output doesn't work" means "AMD GPU doesn't work", which is not necessarily true, because Linux allows you to render something with AMD card and display it with an Intel one. So what do you want? Render with AMD (DRI_PRIME) or use its HDMI output (assuming HDMI is really connected to AMD GPU)? If it's the second one, then I'm afraid you will have to open an issue here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd with some logs and detailed information about your system.

Comment: Hello thanks again for your answer.
when i use DRI_PRIME=1 it returns the AMD GPU that is true. i believe so because when i had windows on this laptop if i unpluged the computer the HDMI stops working i had to change my power settings to keep it working thats why i think it is directly connected to the GPU.
how would you propose to try to render the output via the HDMI.
i tried different settings with xrandr but with no luck.

Comment: I added the log file for because i think something is not running well :)

Comment: My guess is that the GPU is not powered on when the HDMI cable is plugged in. Try manually powering it on by running "DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears" (gears, not info) and while the gears are spinning connect the HDMI cable. Does the HDMI-attached monitor light up correctly?

Comment: Yeah the monitor is fine, because while booting i can see debian logo for like 2 sec before i have to enter the login password then the signal is lost.
Man seriously i don't know how to thank you .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does the experiment I proposed let you use your HDMI-connected monitor? When you close the glxgears window with an HDMI monitor connected does the AMD GPU power off again?

Comment: Sorry i didn't clarify that , no it didn't work.